# How to use separate numbering for first and for second table columns in word processor (e.g. MS Word, Libre Office Writer, etc)?

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice-writer, word-processing

Suppose I have table in rich-text document:

```
┌─┬─┐
│A│D│
├─┼─┤
│B│E│
├─┼─┤
│C│F│
└─┴─┘
```

If I insert numbering in usual way, it'll look like this:

```
┌────┬────┐
│1. A│2. D│
├────┼────┤
│3. B│4. E│
├────┼────┤
│5. C│6. F│
└────┴────┘
```

But I instead want something like this (different variants of same idea):

```
┌────┬────┐    ┌────┬────┐    ┌────┬────────┐
│1. A│1. D│    │1. A│4. D│    │1. A│<K+0>. D│
├────┼────┤    ├────┼────┤    ├────┼────────┤
│2. B│2. E│    │2. B│5. E│    │2. B│<K+1>. E│
├────┼────┤    ├────┼────┤    ├────┼────────┤
│3. C│3. F│    │3. C│6. F│    │3. C│<K+2>. F│
└────┴────┘    └────┴────┘    └────┴────────┘
```

I.e. (two different phrasings of the same thing):

- I want different columns to have individual numbering.
- I want numbering order to be not row/column, but column/row.

Any ideas?
And how cross-platform are your ideas (e.g. "Microsoft Office only", "LibreOffice only", "OpenOffice.org only", "Google Docs only", "LibreOffice + OpenOffice.org", "all desktop offices", etc)?

Upd.: This question got an answer. But it's quite unexpected; I don't understand how it works, nor how I can use it in practice (answer is good, but the way typical word-processor works appear to be quite tangled). So I asked [another question](https://superuser.com/q/1167191/314173).

Comment: Given you want this kind of flexibility, isn't publisher a better option to work in?

Comment: @LPChip, what flexibility?

Comment: Publisher is aimed to create documents with a versatile layout. It has options to design where text is placed, how it is placed and the same is true for images. Think of a newspaper. Publisher is much better suited for creating a newspaper layout than word is. Of course publisher is from the MS Office suite, and every office suite has its alternative.

Comment: @LPChip, I asked "what flexibility" did you see *in my requests* (not in Publisher): as what I request is quite basic thing (not related to layout). Still, thanks for your suggestion: I've never heard of Publisher before (and didn't know that `.pub` it can be opened in LibreOffice since 2012). However, overall `.pub` support seems still to be lower than for `.doc`, `.xls`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer for Word and OpenOffice:

1. To create the first of your three examples, just select each column separately and apply numbering to it.
2. To create the second and third examples, you start by doing the same as #1. Then do one of the following:

   - **In Word:** Right-click the first item in the second column, click **Set Numbering Value**, and enter a value in the **Set value to** field.
   - **In OpenOffice:** On the **Format** menu, click **Bullets and Numbering**, click the **Options** tab, and enter a value in the **Start at** field.

Comment: Yeah, I know that 1st, 2nd and 3rd examples (in the question) can be easily turned from one into another — that's why I considered them as same thing (the was no need to explain how to switch between them; although it may help somebody else).

Comment: As for "just select each column separately and apply numbering to it" — thanks, it does exactly what I needed. Still, it's *very* surprising for me. Because I expected that a number of a paragraph is determined by exactly the two factors: (1) it's numbering style; (2) absence or presence of explicit setting for number value ("continue previous numbering" vs "start with X [for this paragraph]"). Still, it appears not to be true. Any ideas for that?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Word 365 which has slightly different menus and tools from older versions.

If you select the second table then go to the top dropdown FORMAT menu tab, go to Bullet Points and Numbering. At the bottom of the window which opens, it shows 'List numbering'. Simply click on 'Restart numbering'. The second table numbering will begin at 1.

Comment: You probably mean “second column”, not “second table" — am I right?