# Duplicating a column of a table with keeping separate numbering (in word processor, e.g.: MS Word, Libre Office Writer, etc)

Tags: microsoft-word, libreoffice-writer, word-processing

Following [that question](https://superuser.com/q/1166841/314173) on how to make two table columns to have separate numberings.
That question got [answer](https://superuser.com/a/1167024/314173): it appears, that just selecting the second column and applying the same numbering style to it as the first column already has, makes it to have *separate* numbering (of the same style).

But that's quite uncontrollable. For example, assume that I have such (single-column) table:

```
┌─────────────┐
│1. …:        │
│    a) …,    │
│    b) …,    │
│    с) ….    │
├─────────────┤
│2. ….        │
│             │
│Because ….   │
│             │
│Therefore, ….│
├─────────────┤
│3. ….        │
└─────────────┘
```

— i.e. I have column with sequential numbering. But formatting is not so trivial. I have sub-numberings (a, b, c), unnumbered paragraphs ("because …" and "therefore, …") and etc.

How can I duplicate this column? E.g.:

```
┌─────────────┬─────────────┐
│1. …:        │1. …:        │
│    a) …,    │    a) …,    │
│    b) …,    │    b) …,    │
│    с) ….    │    с) ….    │
├─────────────┼─────────────┤
│2. ….        │2. ….        │
│             │             │
│Because ….   │Because ….   │
│             │             │
│Therefore, ….│Therefore, ….│
├─────────────┼─────────────┤
│3. ….        │3. ….        │
└─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

If I just add one more column and copy-paste 1st column into 2nd column (or if I create new two-column table and copy-paste the original column twice into it), I'll get:

```
┌─────────────┬─────────────┐
│1. …:        │2. …:        │
│    a) …,    │    a) …,    │
│    b) …,    │    b) …,    │
│    с) ….    │    с) ….    │
├─────────────┼─────────────┤
│3. ….        │4. ….        │
│             │             │
│Because ….   │Because ….   │
│             │             │
│Therefore, ….│Therefore, ….│
├─────────────┼─────────────┤
│5. ….        │6. ….        │
└─────────────┴─────────────┘
```

I.e. not that I want. For example, let's say, I want to make a translation (first column — one language, second column — other language). Any ideas?

Comment: Your example is quite the same as the first example of the question you've referred to. Have you tried the solution mentioned there? Do you have any issues with it? Exactly what?

Comment: @MátéJuhász, of course, I haven't tried. It makes no sense. I want [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/i7c8d9jW), not [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/uRhGdBCu).

Comment: Have you tried using two separate tables with a page column break in between the tables?

Comment: @DavidPostill, I'm not interested in making them separate tables, because the corresponding cells left and right need to have the same heights. (But the corresponding cells left and right are going to have non-identical text content in future.) (Actually, the purpose of this is to make a paragraph-by-paragraph translation of a contract — so both numbering and rows heights left and right are to be identical, but texts of right cells (and, BTW, of left cells too) will be changed.)